# Reflection error when serializing properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, reflection

I have problems with serializing properties, which are classes implementing some interface.

```
public class A : InterfaceA
{
    public A()
    {
    }
}

public interface InterfaceA
{

}

public class B
{
    public A PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

I'm aware of the problem around serializing interfaces and abstract classes. But does this also belong to properties, which somewhere implement an interface? If this would be the case, you couldn't serialize a Guid either.

> Exception: "Cannot serialize member PropertyA of type InterfaceA because it is an
>   interface."

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to serialize this? (I experienced a similar problem with Newtonsoft.Json and was able to solve it by adding some custom mapping).

Comment: @EJoshuaS Indeed, it could be done with custom mapping. The thing is, I don't want to do that because it's a huge existing project and implementing custom mapping would make it even more complex.

Comment: I assumed that it would add a lot of complexity too actually but it was actually pretty straightforward in Newtonsoft and was decoupled from the rest of the system pretty well. I'm not sure which library you're using or if it would be as simple to implement something like that in your current library but that's one option that's worth looking at.